# Prefilling a form with long request data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http

I am trying to prefill some HTML form fields with data contained in the request.

My original setup, before any changes, looks like this:

**Inside TicketController:**

```
//GET: Retrieve the form
[Route("createticket")]
public ActionResult CreateTicket()
{
    //Irrelevant code ommited

    return View("CreateTicket");
}

//POST: Submit the form
[HttpPost]
[Route("createticket")]
public ActionResult CreateTicket(CreateTicketModel createTicketModel)
{
    //Irrelevant code ommited (saving the submitted data)

    return RedirectToAction("ViewTicket", new { ticketId = ticket.TicketId });
}
```

I could pass the data as a GET parameter, but the problem is often the data will be too long to be contained in the URL (2000+ characters).

The only solution I can currently think of is to make retrieving the form a POST instead of a GET, so I can use POST parameters to prefill the form. I have two problems with this solution:

- I will have two possible POST requests at the /createticket path, which will be conflicting
- It just doesn't feel right to use a POST request to retrieve a form

How could I tackle this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the data will be too long to be contained in the URL"? You have to send data to determine which records to get? I'm not seeing any extra data needed in your Get action.

Comment: Suppose the GET is like this:
public ActionResult CreateTicket(string someData) { ... }
Then I could send the data like this:
/createticket?someData=Some%20Text%20Etcetera
The problem with this would be that the length of the data would be limited by the max length of the url.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you just instantiate a CreateTicket model and set the properties with the data you need to be prefilled? Via model binding the values of your properties will be set into the HTML formfields.

```
[Route("createticket")]
public ActionResult CreateTicket()
{
     //Irrelevant code ommited
     var data = GetSomeDataYouWantToPrefill();
     var model = new CreateTicketModel(data);

     return View("CreateTicket", model);
}
```

Then in the constructor of the model you can assign the values in the data object to the properties. In your view with the Html.TextboxFor method you can bind to the properties in the model